# A combination of three dice

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, dice

It there any formula for calculating dice combinations? For example, for hex-dice, when I roll one die there are six possible results. If I do the same with two dice there are 21 results instead possible 36 because “$1$” with “$2$” is the same as “$2$” with “$1$”. For three dice, there are $6^3 = 216$ combinations, but how many non-repeatable combinations are there? What about $n$ dice?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the $21$ in the case of two dice, without listing the possibilities?

Comment: If our answers were sufficient you can accept an answer by clicking : "accept" under the vote option. This way a question doesn't stay open and people don't open it to see if they can answer your question.

Comment: sauspatz, no i don't. It's just listing.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you determined $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\binom{6+2-1}{2}= \binom{7}{2}= \frac{7!}{5! 2!}= \frac{7 \cdot 6}{2}=7 \cdot 3 = 21$$.

Do you know how to generalise this?

The idea comes from the stars and bars problem, at our university we call it the egg-painting problem (it has something to do with Easter) Suppose we denote the $k$ objects, say eggs, we wish to dye with $n$ colours. We want to find all solutions to the equation:

$$x_1 +x_2 \dots x_n =k $$
Where the $x_i$ denotes which of the $n$ colours we used. and how many. The total number should sum up to the number of eggs. We can also visualise this as follows: there are $n$ buckets, where we just drop a certain amount of eggs in. We denote the walls of the buckets by $1$ and we denote the eggs by $0$. a possible scenario could be:
$$ 0000100$$

This resembles $6$ eggs dyed with $2$ colours.  4 are in the left bucket, two are in the right bucket. In how many ways can we make such an arrangement? Yo already answered this. This is the amount of combinations we can have where two dice can be placed into six boxes of "face numbers". That was equal to $21$.

We need to place $n+k-1$ symbols, because if we place $n-1$ walls as observed above, we still need to place $k$ eggs in buckets of paint. So given the walls, we either place $k$ zeros or given the eggs, we place $n-1$ ones amongst them (the walls). This will give us the identity:

$$ \binom{n+k-1}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{n-1} $$

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: hey if i may ask, how is this related to throwing a dice `n` times and adding up.. i really appreciate if you could explain that

Comment: The eyes of the dice can be coloured  in six ways $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ and there are always three dice, so these are the "eggs".

Comment: This gives us $\binom{6+3-1}{3}=\binom{8}{3}=56$ as mlerma54 remarked.

Comment: Really combinatorics is about counting things in a clever way, so either we talk about putting stars between bars, putting eggs in buckets of paint or putting dice into little boxes with which number they rolled (dice paint)

Comment: Suppose we have an easier number than six, say two- we have a coin. We flip 3 coins, they can be two colours: heads or tails. How many outcomes are there for 3 coins? $\binom{3+2-1}{3}= \binom{4}{3}=\binom{4}{1} =4$  and indeed we have HHT, TTH, TTT or HHH.

Comment: thank you so much :) just to see if i get this, consider 2 dice case. you're saying we can visualize 6 buckets and 2 eggs. This is same as solving $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=2$$

where $x_i\ge 0$ ?

Comment: Yes indeed! and then the number of solutions is the amount of ways to arrange these dice. A solution could be $x_1=2$ and $x_i =0$ for $i= 2, \dots 6$

Comment: you're awesome!  im gona do few problems to get hang of these, thank you again :)

Comment: https://cameroncounts.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/comb.pdf this is a nice textbook/lecture notes on combinatorics if you are interested

Answer (score 2):

That is a particular case of combinations with repetitions. The general formula for combinations of $n$ objects taken $r$ at a time with repetition is $\binom{n+r+1}{r}$ - see e.g. https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/cs310-05s/notes/dm-gcomb

So for $n=6$ and $r=3$ we get $\binom{6+3-1}{3} = \binom{8}{3} = 56$.